# Applying arange for simultaneous computation of multiple ranges

Tags: python, numpy, range

I am having some difficulty computing multiple ranges over a list of lists.
Here is what I have attempted:

```
import numpy as np
k=[[0.0234,0.131,0.475,0.393,0.620],[0.0234,0.131,0.475,0.393,0.620]]
tak=[]
def thresh(a,b):
    for x in k:
        m=[val for val in x if a<=val<=b]
        tak.append(m)
    return tak


t1=np.arange(0.1,0.4,0.1)
for x in t1:
    t2=thresh(x,0.5)
print t2

Output obtained:[[0.131, 0.475, 0.393], [0.131, 0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475], [0.475]]

Desired Output:[[[0.131, 0.475, 0.393],[0.475, 0.393],[0.475, 0.393],[0.475]],[[0.131, 0.475, 0.393],[0.475, 0.393],[0.475, 0.393],[0.475]]]
```

The problem in the code is, it computes the ranges over the two lists simultaneously, instead of addressing one list at a time.

Any suggestions as to how to get around this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order of loop evaluation is not correct. You need to ensure what you are iterating upon and in what order, because it would finally impact your output structure.

Here is a possible implementation after correction of order

```
k=[[0.0234,0.131,0.475,0.393,0.620],[0.0234,0.131,0.475,0.393,0.620]]
t1=np.arange(0.1,0.4,0.1)
def thresh(k, start, end):
    for x in k:
        yield [[val for val in x if s<=val<=end] for s in start]


list(thresh(k, t1,0.5))
[[[0.131, 0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475]], [[0.131, 0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475]]]
```

Comment: many thanks for the solution., it works. I will take a closer look at my loop.

Answer (score 1):

You loop in wrong order, got desired result you have to apply treshold by sublist:

```
def thresh(lst, a,b):
    return [val for val in lst if a<=val<=b]

def apply_tresh(lst, starts, stop):
    rv = []
    for sublst in lst:
        sublv = []
        for start in starts:
            sublv.append(thresh(sublst, start, stop))
        rv.append(sublv)
    return rv
```

Demo:

```
>>> apply_tresh(k, np.arange(0.1,0.4,0.1), 0.5)
[[[0.131, 0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475]], [[0.131, 0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475, 0.393], [0.475]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks to me like it works as expected. The thresh function filters the members of your k list to only those in [a,b]. So

x = 0.1; include only numbers between 0.1 and 0.5

```
[[0.131,0.475,0.393], [0.131,0.475,0.393]]

x=0.2:[[ 0.475, 0.393], [0.475,0.393]]
```

and so forth.

I can't tell how you get to your desired output.

Comment: thanks for responding, however the output I obtained is not my desired output. The problem in the code is, it computes the ranges over the two lists simultaneously, instead of addressing one list at a time.